# Long differential equation question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the equation

$$xy'-y=(x+y) \ln \left(\dfrac{x+y}{x}\right)$$

To solve this equation, I first thought about replacing variables, but my friend suggested that I solve this with Lagrange. How can this be solved this Lagrange, because it seems odd to me? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a substitution $z=1+\frac{y}{x}$. This substitution gives me an equation $$z^{'}x=z\ln z$$

Comment: I love you. :))